# How does sympy simplify ln((exp(x)+1)/exp(x)) to log(1+exp(-x))?

Tags: python, sympy

If I use `simplify()` function in sympy, `log((exp(x)+1)/exp(x))` does simplify to `log(1+exp(-x))`, however, as I read the doc, the simplify function is "can be unnecessarily slow", I tried other simplification methods, but non of them works, so I'm wondering how do I simplify `ln((exp(x)+1)/exp(x))` to the form like this `log(1+exp(-x))` without calling simplify().

Comment: Have you experienced the function being "unnecessarily slow" ? Simplification of mathematical functions is not a particularly easy task.  I'd look at http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/simplify/simplify.html to help understand what the function does.

Comment: I think another problem is it's unpredictable because it choose the answer based on it's length. My job is to compare two equations, so I do need the result to be predictable, I'm trying to use functions in the simplify doc, but can't get any of them to work unless I use simplify()

Comment: The desired result arises immediately for me...I am using Sympy 1.0.

Comment: I'm using 1.0 too and it only shows the desired result if I use simplify() function, but I don't really want to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can more directly just use [**`sympy.polys.polytools.cancel()`**](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html?highlight=cancel#sympy.polys.polytools.cancel), which is available as a method on your expression with `.cancel()`.

```
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> from sympy import *
>>> my_expr = log((exp(x)+1)/exp(x))
>>> my_expr.cancel()
log(1 + exp(-x))
```

This is what is doing the work of simplifying your expression inside `simplify()`.

A very naive benchmark:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> %timeit my_expr.simplify()
100 loops, best of 3: 7.78 ms per loop
>>> %timeit my_expr.cancel()
1000 loops, best of 3: 972 µs per loop
```

---

**Edit**: This isn't a stable solution, and I would advise that you take a look at [asmeurer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880320/how-does-sympy-simplify-lnexpx1-expx-to-log1exp-x/38905278#38905278) where he suggests using [**`expand()`**](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/simplification.html#expand).

Comment: I noticed that it behave differently in different versions, I updated to the newest version (1.0.1.dev0) and it works perfectly however it doesn't cancel out in version 1.0

Comment: @MichaelYuxiDong `cancel` works for me in SymPy 1.0.

Answer (score 4):

The exact function you want to use depends on the general form of the expressions you are dealing with. `cancel` apparently works, but perhaps only by accident. In general, `cancel` cancels common factors from a numerator and denominator, like `cancel((x**2 - 1)/(x - 1))` -> `x + 1`. I think it is only working here because it represents the expression in terms of `exp(-x)`. If it instead used `exp(x)`, it wouldn't simplify, because `(x + 1)/x` doesn't have any common factors. This might be why you are seeing different results from `cancel` in different versions. See [this issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/11506) for more information.

For this expression, I would use **expand()** (or the more targeted `expand_mul`). `expand` will distribute the denominator over the numerator, i.e., `(exp(x) + 1)/exp(x)` will become `exp(x)/exp(x) + 1/exp(x)`. SymPy then automatically cancels `exp(x)/exp(x)` into `1` and converts `1/exp(x)` into `exp(-x)` (they are internally both represented the same way).

```
In [1]: log((exp(x)+1)/exp(x)).expand()
Out[1]:
   ⎛     -x⎞
log⎝1 + ℯ  ⎠
```

There's a guide on some of the simplification functions in the [tutorial](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html).

Comment: This is clearly a better answer than stumbling upon `cancel` :)